# How to command with Notepad++ to organize a huge list?

Tags: list, command, notepad++

Hey i would like to know if there a kind of command may organize a huge list, for example below:

**Before:**

```
hello:world
mars:jupiter
bomb:fire
water:earth
wind:cosmo
```

**After:**

```
hello
world
mars
jupiter
bomb
fire
water
earth
wind
cosmo
```

This example explains removing `:` and add a line after of this character. I couldn't do it by my hands because it contains more than 12,000 lines

If is not possible with Notepad++. Then other tools are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find/replace in extended mode in which you can specify \r\n. Ie, replace ':' with '\r\n'.

Comment: It worked! thanks for your answer :) PD: my Notepad++ is freezing because it's processing for more than 12,000 lines, i hope everything is fine!